# Low accuracy and high loss in multi-class classification

Tags: deep-learning, keras, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to classify images in [17 flowers](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/flowers/17/) dataset which consist of 1360 images of 17 classes (80 images per class); I have to use DNNs only therefore I made my model with the following settings:

```
images_net = models.Sequential([layers.Dense(300,input_dim = 3072, activation='relu'),
                                    layers.Dense(30,activation='relu'),
                                    layers.Dense(17,activation='softmax')]);

images_net.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy']);

my_net = images_net.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),batch_size=32,epochs=10)
```

finally, when I evaluate my model I get the following result:

[image: co]

Can anyone explain the result and what the problem is with these settings?

Comment: Hard to help you without more information. What images are you trying to classify, what are the stats of the dataset your using (e.g. size), do you have an expectation about the final performance of the model, i.e. are you trying to replicate some results or just trying your luck? Also loss and metrics are easier to understand when plotted in separate graphs. For now the only striking thing is that you're using a dense neural net rather than a CNN, any reason for that?

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero I've just edited my question; In addition, I don't have any specific expectations from the performance of the model, I actually looking for a reasonable result.

Answer (score 1):

### Your model is completely underfit

**Reasons:**

1. You have a very small neural network that can't generalize your problem.
2. you mentioned 17 classes but in the last layers, you are specifying 16 class `layers. Dense(16,activation='softmax')` try to fix this.
3. If there is a class imbalance you have to remove this which may make your results worst.
4. Add more `epochs` after adding more layers or use pre-trained models.

**Try this code and models:**

```
base_model = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(512,512,3))
 
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)

prediction = Dense(17, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),batch_size=32,epochs=10)
```

**Evaulate Model:**

```
print(history.history.keys())
#  "Accuracy"
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# "Loss"
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the data, but the model has already 0.9 million trainable parameters so isn't super simple either. But it has very few layers and no convolutions at all, which doesn't seem ideal. But I agree with all of your other points.

Comment: share your code I will let them with better accuracy